# in PayPal , how to get client id and secret from email

Tags: email, paypal, integration, secret-key, clientid

Now I am working for integrating PayPal.

For PayPal actions including subscription and so on, it needs client id and secret.

For obtaining client id and secret, is there any way to obtaining these from paypal email address?

or maybe is there any way to do subscription and so on without client id, and secret?

Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: google it:  `braintree payments`

Comment: @num8er, is it impossible without braintree?

Comment: just cannot understand Your issue. Everything is explained in official documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/  You need to get from developer console of paypal Your client_id and secret and use it.

Comment: watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7k03jobKGXM

Comment: @num8er, thanks for your response, I think you are a expert. I posted some more questions, and I think those are simple questions, but nobody answered yet. can you see these questions and let me know how to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144240/how-can-look-paypal-plans-in-dashboard , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144240/how-can-look-paypal-plans-in-dashboard , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50141252/in-paypal-how-can-i-get-account-id-or-any-information-like-stripe